# Branch name policy for Githhub repo branches

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on git. While creating a branch in this repo I want my dev team to follow a naming pattern. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could enforce both a client and server side hook, which checks the names of all branches, and maybe gives error feedback if the name doesn't match your pattern.  But you could also just tell everyone what the convention is.  Maybe they would just "get it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing a policy is generally done on the server side, because a client hook must be distributed to *all* user (and when that policy change, you need to distribute it again)

However, if you don't have direct access to the server (like in a github.com repo), then you need to put in place a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).